# Не могу изменить display

Tags: javascript

Подскажите где ошибка...
Хочу изменить display на none в блоке

```
<div id='bodyLayer' style='display:block;'>.
```

при выполнении:

```
document.getElementById('bodyLayer').style.display='none';
```

выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Но при проверки в консоли:

```
document.getElementById('bodyLayer').style.display='none';
```

возвращает none как и должен.

P.S. Нужно чтоб подсказали где ошибка, а не написали рабочий код.

Comment: Проверьте, там ли вы ищете элемент. Введи в консоле `document.getElementById('bodyLayer')` и посмотрите результат

Comment: Поместите Ваш код, который должен работать с элементами DOM в [onDOMContentLoaded](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

Comment: Проверил в консоли document.getElementById('bodyLayer') 
Объект найден <div id='bodyLayer' style='display:block;'></div>

Comment: Скорее всего у вас код выполняется раньше, чем создается сам элемент. Попробуйте выполнять код по onDOMContentLoaded, как сказал ReinRaus, или просто поместите его в конец страницы.

Comment: Возможно, проблема связана тем, что стиль 

    display: block;

у Вас прописан inline и как следствие имеет больший приоритет, поэтому JS не может переопределить данный стиль. Попробуйте стиль прописать не в элементе, а в таблице стилей.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно js код выполняется перед формированием DOM элементов. Подключите js файл в конце страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего элемент не добавлен в документ, потому и поиск по id возвращает null, не смотря на то, что элемент уже создан